# swt table change selection item color

Tags: select, swt, selection

I'm using a standard swt table which, as you may know, by default when an item is selected is colored blue (windows standard). When the selection is inactive, it turns light gray. I would like to override both colors... I've searched all over the web but could only find some very old code which no longer seems to work with the table widget.

Below is some sample code I was trying to overwrite the default color but it doesn't seem to be working (please excuse the dirty code, was just trying to get something to work):

```
    table.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
            Color rowSelectionColor = 
                            new Color(Display.getCurrent(),new RGB(235, 200, 211));
                            TableItem item =(TableItem)event.item;
                item.setBackground(0,rowSelectionColor);
                item.setBackground(1,rowSelectionColor);
                item.setBackground(2,rowSelectionColor);


            }

            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
            Color rowSelectionColor = 
                            new Color(Display.getCurrent(),new RGB(235, 200, 211));
                            TableItem item =(TableItem)event.item;
                item.setBackground(0,rowSelectionColor);
                item.setBackground(1,rowSelectionColor);
                item.setBackground(2,rowSelectionColor);


            }
        });
```

Any ideas would be greaaatly massively appreciated :D

Answer (score 4):

If you want to go with a TableViewer to manage your table, you can use a StyledCellLabelProvider to determine the colors/fonts/etc for individual cells. The TableViewer will take care of the "owner draw" aspects for you. The biggest hassle is setting up the ContentProvider, LabelProvider, and input classes that go with the TableViewer.

Comment: More: subclass StyledCellLabelProvider, override the update(ViewerCell) method, use ViewerCell.getElement() to get the row element, call cell.setText() appropriately, and set colors through the cell as well.