# How to change SWT Table Item selection background color

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface, rcp

I have a similar use case as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941219/swt-table-change-selection-item-color). I want to change the SWT Table Item selection background color from default grey or blue to some other color. I tried using the StyledCellLabelProvider#update method but it was of no use. It simply updates the background color for all table items to the given color. But I need it to be only for the selected item. Below is the code Snippet of my label provider update method

```java
@Override
public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
    cell.setText(provider.getDisplay((T) cell.getElement(), cell.getColumnIndex()));
    TableItem currentTableItem = ((TableItem) cell.getViewerRow().getItem());
    if (currentTableItem.getParent().getSelectionCount() > 0) {
        TableItem selectedTableItem = currentTableItem.getParent().getSelection()[0];
        if(currentTableItem == selectedTableItem) {
            cell.setBackground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_LIST_SELECTION));            
        }
    }
    cell.setForeground(provider.getDisplayColor((T) cell.getElement(), cell.getColumnIndex()));
    super.update(cell);
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The selection colour is normally chosen by the OS, so to change the colour you have to turn off the selected flag in the `StyledCellLabelProvider` `erase`, `measure` and `paint` methods. You also have to draw the selection colour yourself in the `erase` method.

Something like the following:

```java
  @Override
  protected void erase(final Event event, final Object element)
  {
    if ((event.detail & SWT.SELECTED) != 0) {
      event.detail &= ~SWT.SELECTED;
  
      Rectangle bounds = event.getBounds();

      event.gc.setBackground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_LIST_SELECTION));
   
      event.gc.fillRectangle(bounds);
    }

    super.erase(event, element);
  }

  @Override
  protected void measure(final Event event, final Object element)
  {
    event.detail &= ~SWT.SELECTED;

    super.measure(event, element);
  }

  @Override
  protected void paint(final Event event, final Object element)
  {
    event.detail &= ~SWT.SELECTED;

    super.paint(event, element);
  }
```